# How to compile node.js module canvas on RedHat OpenShift servers?

Tags: node.js, canvas, openshift, cairo

On RedHat OpenShift servers it is not possible to compile node.js module canvas, because there are missing cairo libraries for the linux, and related required libraries as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
This is how to make it compile:

export PATH=/sbin:$PATH:$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local/lib:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
curl -L http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/1.6.17/libpng-1.6.17.tar.gz/download -o libpng.tar.gz
curl -L http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz -o jpegsrc.tar.gz
curl -L http://www.cairographics.org/releases/pixman-0.32.6.tar.gz -o pixman.tar.gz  
curl -L http://public.p-knowledge.co.jp/Savannah-nongnu-mirror//freetype/freetype-2.5.5.tar.gz -o freetype.tar.gz
curl -L http://www.cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.14.2.tar.xz -o cairo.tar.xz  
curl -L http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.35/pango-1.35.3.tar.xz -o pango.tar.xz
curl -L http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/fontconfig-2.11.1.tar.gz -o fontconfig.tar.gz
curl -L http://www.freedesktop.org/software/harfbuzz/release/harfbuzz-0.9.37.tar.bz2 -o harfbuzz.tar.bz2
curl -L http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glib/2.34/glib-2.34.3.tar.xz -o glib.tar.xz
curl -L http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.35/pango-1.35.3.tar.xz -o pango.tar.xz
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
gunzip libpng.tar.gz
tar -xvf libpng.tar
cd libpng-1.6.17/
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar -zxf jpegsrc.tar.gz && cd jpeg-9a/
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local 
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar -zxf pixman.tar.gz && cd pixman-0.32.6/  
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local  
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar -zxf freetype.tar.gz && cd freetype-2.5.5/
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local  
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar --xz -xvf cairo.tar.xz && cd cairo-1.14.2/
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --without-x --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar -xvf fontconfig.tar.gz && cd fontconfig-2.11.1/
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
bunzip2 harfbuzz.tar.bz2
tar -xvf harfbuzz.tar && cd harfbuzz-0.9.37/
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar --xz -xvf glib.tar.xz && cd glib-2.34.3/
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
tar --xz -xvf pango.tar.xz && cd pango-1.35.3/
./configure --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local
make
make install
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
scl enable nodejs010 v8314 'npm install canvas'   
rm -rf "${OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_DIR}/tmp/saved.node_modules"
```

To use these libraries in the node.js server, you need to add custom LD_LIBRARY_PATH entry which points to them:

In the OpenShift git project add directory: .openshift/markers
In this directory create empty file named: use_npm

In the package.json file add this entry:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/local/lib:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; supervisor server.js"
  }
```

This usually works, but sometimes there are happening npm update activities which start to rebuild canvas module.

Sometimes bcrypt module does not build too.

The solution is to create one gear, where everything just works, and then to make tar.gz file with the contents of $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/usr/
and to transfer this file to your server where it is accessible via http://

That same should be done for node_modules/canvas, node_modules/bcrypt and other vulnerable entries.

Then, it is possible to use OpenShift app hooks (build, etc) to download and extraxt the contents of these files in the right places.

Also, you can compile many node_modules/xxxxx on the CentOS 6.6, and then to copy these in the right places on the server, which runs RHEL 6.6
(binary compatibility stuff, just like with rpm package installation)

This way it is possible to create git repository and downloadable tar.gz files which would allow to automatically launch new RedHat OpenShift gears.

Of course, if there will be some system upgrades, tar.gz files contents must be upgraded too.

Comment: You need to install glib before harfbuzz though, or pango will complain that hb-glib.h doesn't exist because harfbuzz won't include glib.

Comment: the file was an html, found this and it worked: http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/libpng/